# Intercept navigator.usb.requestDevice dialog with puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, webusb

Is it possible to intercept the dialog created after requesting a usb device via `navigator.usb.requestDevice`? I tried `page.on("dialog", dialog => ()` from the puppeteer script  and `document.addEventListener('dialog', () => ...)` from the page DOM but none of those callbacks were invoked.

[image: Dialog]

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible today but it is something the Chromium project is aware developers are interested in.

To help prioritize this feature, can you say what your use case for automating this dialog is?

Comment: just found my way here - fwiw, my use-case is pretty straightforward: i'm building a webapp to service IoT devices. i want to create end-to-end tests for the app which automate a setup process against a preconfigured device. basically, start with "new" device, end with "provisioned" device === passing.